# Validation at node_presave in drupal 6

Tags: 6, hooks, nodes, forms

I received a somewhat complicated Drupal 6 application to maintain and unfortunately I am quite a newbie with Drupal.

The task is to verify certain system variable is set before saving the node. Is the node_presave ok place to do this? And how can I abort the saving process?

It should fail silently with a log message.

Comment: Do you want to set variable before saving the node or validate node?

Answer (score 3):

No, `hook_nodeapi op=presave` is the wrong place for that.

You should instead use `hook_nodeapi op=validate`

> "validate": The user has just finished editing the node and is trying
>   to preview or submit it. This hook can be used to check the node data.
>   Errors should be set with form_set_error().

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6

However, it won't fail silently, instead showing an error on the node form.